# Connecting mysql tables on localhost with different port numbers

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection-string

I have 2 tables one is in local database and other one is on remote server.
I use port forwarding in C# to get my ssh remote connection to the localhost:3306 my local database is on localhost:3307

How can I copy one table to another one if they are both on localhost but with different ports.

This is my query that I want to do:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (a,b,c,d) SELECT (a,b,c,d) FROM {1}", ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_table"), ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main_table")), con);
```

Both tables have same columns and that is why I am using only one input from config settings.

But I have 2 connections strings as they are on different ports.

```
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
con2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString
```

Is there any way to get my query to work with those 2 ports as I don't want to be using FEDERATED connection in MySql. There must be the way as they are both on the same server.

Thank you

EDIT:

Connection strings:

```
<add name="Con2" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3307;user id=root;Password=*****;database=data" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<add name="Con1" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;user id=root;Password=******;database=data" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Removed my answer. I see that you want to perform the insert using only one connection. I don't know if it is possibile. Looking around if I find something.

Comment: I look something that will make this work from c# so for example I can read select from one and save it somewhere and insert it into another table if necessary.

Comment: If you are ok with using separate connections then you could read all of your required data inside a DataTable then create an empty datatable from the second connection, then copy data via LoadDataRow in the second table and then write back the new records of the second datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode to move data between two separate tables on two different connection

1. Create/Open the connection to the first MySql
2. Create/Run a query to get data inside a DataTable from first MySql
3. Create/Open the connection to the second MySql
4. Create/Run a query to get data inside a DataTable from second MySql without records (using WHERE 1=0 or something like that)
5. Loop on the rows of the first DataTable
6. Call ImportRow on the second table passing the values from the
   first row
7. Save the second datatable

   ```
   DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
   using(MySqlConnection cn1 = GetConnection("first_connection_string");
   {
       cn1.Open();
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select x,x,x,x from t1", cn1);
       MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
       da.SelectCommand = cmd;
       da.Fill(dtSource);
   }

   DataTable dtDest = new DataTable();
   using(MySqlConnection cn2 = GetConnection("second_connection_string");
   {
       cn2.Open();
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select x,x,x,x from t2 where 1=0", cn2);
       MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
       da2.SelectCommand = cmd;
       da2.Fill(dtDest);

       foreach(DataRow r in dtSource)
           dtDest.ImportRow(r);

       da2.Update(dtDest);
   }
   ```

**Please note that this has not been tested. Take it as experimental.**

EDIT: Seeing the comments  I will add another way to update the second table

```
    using(MySqlConnection cn2 = GetConnection("second_connection_string");
    {
        cn2.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO T2 (a,b) values(@a,@b)", cn2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", string.Empty); // Suppose the "a" field is a string
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", string.Empty); // Suppose the "b" field is a string

        foreach(DataRow r in dtSource)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@a"].Value = r["a"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters["@b"].Value = r["b"].ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

This is in the case you don't need to insert a whole record from the dtSource in the destination table. In this case I revert to an INSERT command with parameters, loop on the source table, insert in the destination table

Comment: This is good example- In the second query I want to insert all from table one to table 2, Why do you select 2 times?

Comment: In first query I have put SELEECT * from Data and in second one should go something like insert...

Comment: The first query loads data, the second select serves only to give a schema to the datatable without data. Then the select command is used from the da2 to derive the INSERT and UPDATE commands to execute against data in dtDest

Comment: I have put same queries int first and second one. Only on the second I didn't where statement, I am debugging and I can't get trough this part `da.Fill(dtSource);`- this is trowing me null exception. Do I need to initialize it somehow?

Comment: Yes, put a dtDest = new DataTable(); instead of dtDest = null just before entering the second using statement

Comment: This is going trough normally but I don't see any resoults in database. For example I have in table1(id,a,b) and in table2(id,a,b) I want to copy a , b from table2 to table1

Comment: Hi Steve this is great example. But here is the deal. For example I am writing records in the database like every 5 sec. Now if I have like 3-4k of records will this method of looping be fast? Any idea how to make it faster. I just need to copy one table to antoher with no id... You really help me a lot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12071/discussion-between-denonth-and-steve)

Comment: steve can you please help me with your example. I have tried it like 100 times and I keep getting input string error. Like I didn't matched right values. Can you please help me. My email is denonth.jesus@gmail.com can you send me an email so I can send you part of my code to see if we are on the same page :)